# LINQ Statement dictionary first key's value

Tags: linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
private Dictionary<string, string> ScannerMessages;
```

and then I have a call for this

```
public bool equalMessages()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            return (ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Distinct().Count() < ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Count) ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

And it returns if the messages are equal. I also need to add to the end of that clause a second check to verify that the values are not null or empty. I was trying to do something like this but I am not sure where to go with the LINQ statement (not the greatest at LINQ)...

```
public bool equalMessages()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            return ((ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Distinct().Count() < ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Count) && (ScannerMessages.Keys.First() *get the value here and check it !null or string.empty) ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify all the values are not null or empty:

```
ScannerMessages.Values.All(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
```

It will return true if all values are not null and not empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the non-null values you can do this:

```
ScannerMessages.Values.Where(v=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(v)).ToList()
```

or just to get the count

```
ScannerMessages.Values.Where(v=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(v)).Count()
```

or

```
ScannerMessages[ScannerMessages.Keys.First()].Where(v=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(v)).Count()
```

Comment: That is very close to what I need. I have edited my statement to be return ((ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Distinct().Count() < ScannerMessages.Values.ToList().Count) && (ScannerMessages[ScannerMessages.Keys.First()].Where(v=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(v)).Count() > 0)) ? true : false; but I do get an invalid argument error on this piece "string.IsNullOrEmpty(v)"